# CDI discovery-mode annotated doesn't scan stereotypes bean

Tags: java, jsf, cdi, stereotype

Why `bean-discovery-mode="annotated"` doesn't scan beans annotated with some stereotype, such as `@Model` - I just tried that and classes annotated this way weren't pick up by CDI so I had to change the mode back to the `all`. So is this a bug (because for instance `@Model` has a scope) or is this by design?

Comment: What CDI implementation and version are you using?

Comment: CDI 1.1 with default Weld (java-ee 7 Maven dependency).

Comment: That doesn't make much sense.  You need to have an implementation on your classpath.  Can you possibly post your POM?  If you're deploying to an application server, please specify which one and the version.

Comment: Wildfly 8.1.0.Final - which means Weld 2.1.Final.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the `bean-discovery-mode="annotated"` in CDI 1.1, only beans annotated with a *bean defining annotation* are picked up by CDI as beans. This is described in the [CDI 1.1 specification, chapter 2.5](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.1/cdi-spec.html#bean_defining_annotations). As can be seen there, stereotypes are *not* included in the set of bean-defining annotations. Only scope types are bean-defining.

The `@Model` annotation is a built-in CDI stereotype. Therefore in CDI 1.1, annotating a bean `@Model` is not enough to get it discovered in the `annotated` discovery mode.

This is, however, going to change with CDI 1.2 ([chapter 2.5.1](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#bean_defining_annotations)), where stereotypes *are* considered bean-defining annotations.